# Error in Galaxybase execution of Cypher query: execution blocking time exceeds the limit

Tags: graph-databases

Several Cypher tasks were performed in Galaxybase in parallel, and the following error messages were reported:

```
    @ErrReason
    @ErrSolution
    CYPHER_QUERY_EXCEEDS(
            en：CYPHER_TASK.getEn() + " execution blocking time exceeds the limit!"
    ),
```

I don't know which step is wrong. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The database has set the concurrency limit for each user query, the default concurrency limit is 5 for query statement and 1 for call statement.

The task that exceeds the concurrency limit will enter the wait state, if the wait time exceeds the upper limit of ther database system configuration, the exception will be given.

You can modify the task blocking time in the system configuration through the administrator account, or modify the concurrency limit for the user. (Note that the concurrency limit CAN NOT BE LARGER than the number of CPU cores of the system.